# C++/CLI global function accessibility issue

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

How can I make a C++/CLI function visible, when the compiled DLL is imported in C#?

I can do it with classes simply by preceding their name with public, but its not the case with functions and I get syntax error when I do so.

Comment: C++/CLI uses a different syntax than C#. Do you know how to declare a function `public` in C++? Hint: try putting a colon between public and the function declaration.

Comment: Well, in C++ you declare a function public, I mean accessible from everywhere, simply by doing nothing! and declaring it in the global namespace. That's how I've done under Linux all the time. Here's the case is C++/CLI. And `public:` doesn't work too! Thanks, though I need more help @CodyGray

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't, the CLR does not support global functions.  You can write them in C++/CLI but the compiler generates a special class to give them a home.  The class name is `<Module>`, it is not accessible from C# code.

You'll get the exact equivalent by declaring a public ref class with public static methods.  No trouble accessing those.  Same idea as a static class in C#, minus the checks.  You can add the checks by declaring it abstract and sealed:

```
public ref class Utils abstract sealed
{
public:
    void static foo() {}
};
```